# why scatterplot3js overlays plots when input dataset is changed?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use scatterplot3js and give it different datasets given by the user. However, if I change the dataset, it tries to plot them together. I tried to change the renderer (renderer='webgl') it does not work.

```
library(threejs)
library(shiny)
get.dt <- function(x) switch(x, rock = rock, mtcars = mtcars)
app <- shinyApp(
     ui = bootstrapPage(
       selectInput("data", "dataset", c("rock", "mtcars") ),
       scatterplotThreeOutput('plot')
     ),
     server = function(input, output) {
       output$plot <- renderScatterplotThree({ 
       data <- get.dt(input$data)
       scatterplot3js(as.matrix(data[,1:3]))
  })
     }
   )
   runApp(app)
 }
```

Comment: works very fine on win_7 + R_3.3.2 + Shiny_1.0.0 + threejs_0.2.2

Comment: Hi @HubertL thanks. I'm on ubuntu, just updated to shiny_1.0.0. I was trying the theejs 0.3 from github, with 0.2.2 it works, but I can't see spheres as points using renderer="webgl", and the manual says that it will be needed with a large number of points.